# Asp.net SQL server instance not found or not accessible

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, instance, accessible

I'm working on a web project, when I was using the vs2008 everything works fine. But after I use another machine and work under vs2012 using the same way setting up the project, exception always saying instance not found or not accessible.

I have google the solution but they're using the SQL server management tool to solve it.

I just installed the vs2012, do I need to install a new SQL server 2012 to get those tools o configure it?

Thanks very much

Comment: This is a Database issue, nothing to do with Visual studio. Check the connection settings.

Comment: @ChrisBint so does it mean I have to install the SQL? Since there is no SQL tools in my machine though visual studio include the SQL server basic function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i got the simple solution in my case.
what I've done is just

1. install SQL SERVER 2012 EXPRESS
2. open the SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER
3. go to SQL SERVER NETWORK CONFIGURATION on the left panel
4. expand it and select the protocol for particular SERVER
5. on the right panel, enable the TCP/IP
6. restart the corresponding server

after these steps, all done.

since some of the SQL SERVER setting would disable the TCP/IP by default.

so even when we install Visual Studio, we still couldn't ensure the server is able to be used.

Then what we have to do is to download and Install SQL Server Express at least in order to get the configuration tool.

Honestly this is my first time encountering this kind of problem which is all because of Visual Studio 2012.

hopefully this could help those who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that SQL Connection string is valid, such as IP address/Hostname, Username, Password.

Comment: actually I have tried in different ways. those ways work perfectly in vs2008 n 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this type of error, but now i'm using the new Microsoft SQL server 2017, and this is successfully run on my machine i suggest that  try this new version, Here is the link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017  , hope you like it.. try once.!